# Using class self.varname in __init__ args

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I was just wondering if there is a short hand is python for having variables initialized in a class. I know that:

```py
class myclass():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

works, but I was wondering if there was a short hand. The way python3 already does this is probably the the best because it's more flexable to the different types of `__init__()` methods that could be written but I wondering if there is way to do this that is shorter to write out?

I tried using `self.a` as argument for `__init__()` and it didn't work.

```py
Python 3.7.5rc1 (default, Oct  8 2019, 16:47:45) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190909] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class myclass():
...     def __init__(self, self.a):
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    def __init__(self, self.a):
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's not a big deal if no other syntax exists.

Comment: Are you aware of dataclasses and the attrs library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MyClass():
    a: int   # A type is required; replace int with whatever type a should be
```

The decorator takes care of generating, among other things, an `__init__` method that sets `self.a` with a given argument.

```
>>> x = MyClass(3)
>>> x.a
3
```

Comment: This isn't a shortcut - this is different solution that solves some of the issues, and creates others.

Comment: What issue does it not solve? What issue does it create?

Comment: @cherper - dataclasses don't do private attributes at all, unless you want all of your keyword arguments to start with an underscore. Yes they write some of the bioler plate - yippee - but if you need a fully functional class as a mapping, or a number, or a customised container you still have to write all of that.
Dataclasses are good for one job - a data container with public attrirbutes with nicely formatted comparisons and str and repr formats. They aren't a general purpose substitute for writing classes with deep  functionality.

Comment: You do realize you can define other methods explicitly, to go along with the ones generated by the decorator, right? And you can define additional attributes by using `field(init=False)` and defining `__post_init__`?

Comment: And I still get all of my arguments made as public attributes - which if you are writing a fully featured class with properties to protect internal then making  everything a public attributes a bad idea. It all depends on what you need. Dataclasses do not solve everything and were never intended to do so. They are useful for one given use case.

Comment: I'm really not sure what your concern is. Adding `a: int = 0` doesn't make `a` a public attribute; it just means the generated `__init__` method takes an argument `a` used to execute `self.a = a`. Define a property named `a`, and that assignment uses the setter. Define `_a: int = field(init=False)`, and the attribute isn't exposed by `__init__` at all.

Comment: The use shown here addresses *exactly* what the OP is asking about.

Comment: but claiming that it is a shortcut is not true - it isn't - it is an alternative implementation with different features. Not a shortcut. Does it solve the problem - maybe; does it introduce issues - maybe. It all depends exactly what the OP is attempting - a small code snippet doesn't show the whole intention. I decided that I wouldn't guess.

Comment: If the OP has other requirements, they can include them in the question. I see no reason to avoid using a dataclass here simply because does not know how to fully exploit them.

Comment: I accept that dataclasses might be a solution - if the OP has that specific use case. They are not a general catch all.

Comment: What "specific use case" are you referring to? `dataclass` doesn't create some special kind of class; it is *literally* just generating some boilerplate for an ordinary class in a well defined manner.

Comment: Dataclasses are intended for the use cases where all of your arguements to the `__init__` are to be public attributes without property wrappers etc. Some people need that some don't. I never claimed they made a special class - I said they are intended for a specific use.
Let's stop this now - this is not what comments are for.

Comment: Since the question asks about assigning ``__init__`` parameters to attributes of the same name – that's exactly what ``dataclass`` does. Assigning parameters to different names, even just private ones, isn't the question.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 You are the only one who appears to be claiming that as the "intended" use. Everything about the `dataclasses` module refutes that claim.

Comment: @cherper - I don't understand what you mean by that comment sorry. The use case for dataclasses is totally clear. Anyway - lets stop this debate - comments are not the right place for extended discussions.

Answer (score -1):

There is no effective shortcut - it is part of the explicit nature of Python that should need to explicitly create your instance variables using the names that you want.

if you really insist on shorter code you could use:

```
class MyClass:
      def __init__(self, a, b, c):
          self.__dict__.update(locals())
```

All the parameters (a, b & c) all exist effectively as local variables in the `__init__` method, so you can update the instance `__dict__` directly; but

- This snippet makes all of your paramters into attributes whether you want them or not
- You need more complex code to make the attributes private - you will need a dictionary comprehension for example - and your stil have the issue above.
- You still need to explicit code if any of your attributes should actually be mutable types (such as lists, dictionaries, sets etc).
- You will end up with a self.self attribute (an attribute on the instance that will refer to itself); clearly not a good idea. (Thank you to [user2357112supportsMonica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) for identifying this).

So while the `__dict__.update` shortcut may look cute, it isn't really a good solution; there are too many common cases that simply aren't handled.

Edit : You could use dataclasses if you know all of your attributes will be public and for example you don't want to use properties to provide wrappers around your attributes. Dataclasses might solve your problems, but it might introduce more issues depending on your exact use case. If all you want to do is save a few lines of code in the `__init__` method, then I think you are doing the wrong thing - explicit is prefered over implicit.

I don't really understand what you were trying to achieve in your second snippet - parameter names to methods can't be dotted names.

Comment: "There is no effective shortcut". That isn't true as of Python 3.7.

Comment: `self.__dict__.update(locals())` is a bad idea. For example, it will set `self.self = self`, because there's a `self` local variable.

Comment: @chepner - what is the Python3.7 shortcut ? Are you refering to dataclasses?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - another reason - thank you.